# Name of a book with the following contents?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory, modules

Some time ago, I received Algebra notes from my advisor who is advising me on a project. I learned very much from these notes and wondered what the name of the book from which these notes were extracted would be. Though I asked my advisor for the source, it was unfortunate that he forgot from where he downloaded the notes. I am not being only curious here but there are some missing pages which I should find in order to finish my reading. Please, help me identify this book.

There contents are the following:

- Chapter 5: Modules $\hspace{7in}$
         5.1 Definitions and examples $\hspace{7in}$
         5.2 Direct Sums $\hspace{7in}$
         5.3 Free Modules $\hspace{7in}$
         5.4 Vector Spaces $\hspace{7in}$
         5.5 Some Pathologies $\hspace{7in}$
         5.6 Quotient Modules $\hspace{7in}$
         5.7 Homomorphisms $\hspace{7in}$
         5.8 Simple Modules $\hspace{7in}$
         5.9 Modules over PID's $\hspace{7in}$
         5.10 Exercises $\hspace{7in}$
         5.11 True/False Statements $\hspace{7in}$
- Chapter 6 Modules with Chain Conditions $\hspace{7in}$
         6.1 Artinian Modules $\hspace{7in}$
         6.1 Noetherian Modules $\hspace{7in}$
         6.3 Modules of Finite Length $\hspace{7in}$
         6.4 Artinian Rings $\hspace{7in}$
         6.5 Noetherian Rings $\hspace{7in}$
         6.6 Radicals: nilradical, Jacobson radical $\hspace{7in}$ 
         6.7 Radical of an Artinian Ring $\hspace{7in}$
         6.8 Exercises $\hspace{7in}$
         6.9 True/False Statements $\hspace{7in}$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that it is the book Introduction to Rings and Modules by C. Musili.
The only thing you had to do was using google:

["Modules with Chain Conditions" "false statements"](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22Modules%20with%20Chain%20Conditions%22%20%22false%20statements%22)

[Musili Rings Modules](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=Musili%20Rings%20Modules)

[Musili Rings Modules "Modules with Chain Conditions" "false statements"](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=Musili%20Rings%20Modules%20%22Modules%20with%20Chain%20Conditions%22%20%22false%20statements%22)

EDIT: I did not mean to be condescending (now that I read my answer again it sounds a little bit like that). Finding that book seemed really easy to me, but I might have been lucky to choose the correct phrases. No hard feelings, I hope.

EDIT2: My strategy was trying to look for some phrases that are not that common. I do not remember seeing "True/False statements" section in many books.

Comment: edited 17 hours ago

 
answered 18 hours ago
Martin
6016
 
 
@Martin, thank you very much. Before I asked, I googled intensively for many days and found nothing. I concentrated on searching only chapter titles and not the subsections. You are really a search expert.